# Is it possible to add options to the right click menu in gedit?

Tags: gedit

More specifically I would like to be able to open terminal at the parent directory, like the open terminal option in nautilus.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Gedit works with plugins. There are 2 that probably do what you want. One is called "Embedded Terminal" and the other "External tools" but both are not part of the default installed plugins. You can add more with

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

And then select these options in then plugins section:

[image]

- "external tools", control, alt, T will open a terminal:

  [image]
- "Embedded terminal" will add a permanent console to the bottom of gedit. You also might need to turn on "bottom panel" from "views":

[image]

And there it is.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I already knew about this. Thanks for a quality response none the less!

Comment: I am more concerned with how one would go about writing a geddit plugin that adds an option to the right click menu, and less concerned with opening a terminal. Such a ubiquitous UI design pattern in a program as fundamental as a text editor should not be relegated to the up echelon of programmer and I really think this question deserves a more thorough answer.